# Add double quotes string to return JSON

Tags: python, scripting

Currently I'm parsing a string using `split` and returning the below

`{fruit1:"Apple",fruit2:"Orange",fruit3:"Pear"}`

I want to convert this string to json using `json.loads` but I get the below error

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`

How would I go about adding double quotes to this string so I can perform the desired result below

```
food = '{"fruit1":"Apple","fruit2":"Orange","fruit3":"Pear"}'

print(food['fruit1'])

-----------

Apple
```

Comment: Why don't you create the string using `json.dumps()` in the first place?

Comment: That isn't JSON input at all. Maybe it's JavaScript? If you created it as JSON you wouldn't have this problem. If you really want to convert other JavaScript into JSON, the best way to do that is with a JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: The easiest way would be to write the string out as proper JSON in the first place.  Where is that string coming from?   Looks like JS as others have said, but JS provides a function to convert objects to valid json: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: You can't reliably add the quotes -- quotes and escape sequences are needed to make the input unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in this case, you can treat the string as a `jq` filter, and use the [Python bindings for `jq`](https://pypi.org/project/jq/) (a third-party package, not in the standard library) to evaluate it to a `dict` object.

```
>>> import jq
>>> d = jq.first('{fruit1:"Apple",fruit2:"Orange",fruit3:"Pear"}', None)
>>> d['fruit1']
'Apple'
```

Comment: I don't see this suggested in the linked duplicate -- it might be worth adding as an answer there.

Comment: I'm happy to let someone else add an answer. I don't know enough JavaScript to know if `jq` filters are a superset of "raw javascript objects".

Comment: Thank you @chepner